# Conditional afterFind based on prefix or page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a behavior with an afterFind function that I only want called on a non-admin prefix.  $this->params does not work, since $this is referencing the behavior.  How can I make this behavior conditional based on the page or prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detach (or disable) behavior in the controller:

> ```
> function beforeFilter(){
>   if($this->params['admin'])$this->Model->Behaviors->detach('Foo');
> }
> ```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1072/Using-Behaviors

Or you can add your own behavior keyword (like 'contain' for Containable) in the find.

Comment: Ended up using disable().  Perfect!  Thanks